# how to get resolved data in $state object with ui-router 1.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building an angular plugin named breadcrumb here, it works fine until I update ui-router version to *'1.0.0-beta.2'*. the cause is that I can't get resolved data from $state.$current.

#### in html

specify display name property to data.displayName in html

`<breadcrumbs display-name-property="data.displayName"></breadcrumbs>`

#### state config

displayName is dynamic

`.state('app.dict.list.tree', {
    ...
    data:    {
        displayName: '{{title}}'
    },
    resolve: {
        title: ['$transition$', $transition$ => $transition$.params().title],
    }
})`

#### directive link function

i use $interpolate service to compile propertyReference(in this case '{{title}}') with the context *$state.$current.locals.global*.

`var currentState = $state.$current;
interpolationContext = (typeof currentState.locals !== 'undefined') ? currentState.locals.globals : currentState;
displayName = $interpolate(propertyReference)(interpolationContext);`

update ui-router to the latest version, this code won't work anymore, currentState.locals is undefined, and I can't find a way to access resolved data in currentState object.

does anybody know how to do it? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: find the solution here [https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#getresolvetokens](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#getresolvetokens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(legacyRouter){
                    scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
                        updateBreadcrumbsArray();
                    });
                }else{
                    $injector.get('$transitions').onSuccess({}, function(trans){
                        resolved(trans, updateBreadcrumbsArray)
                    })
                }

                /**
                 * get all resolved data in state declare and use them to compile display name
                 * */
                function resolved(trans, fn){
                    var tokens = trans.getResolveTokens();
                    var resolves = {};
                    var promises = tokens.map(function(token){
                        var resolved = trans.injector().get(token);
                        resolves[token] = resolved;
                        return resolved;
                    });
                    $q.all(promises).then(function(){
                        fn(resolves);
                    })
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found `$state.getCurrentPath()` gives a list of [pathNodes](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/path.pathnode.html) which includes resolved data.

It is similar to Transition's [treeChanges](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.treechanges.html)().to which is available only when transition occurs